# sumar valores de inputs dependiendo de select jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quisiera los totales de las cuentas pero depende del select se que se haya seleccionado

```js
$(".formapago").change(function () {
            var tipo = $(this).val();
            var total = 0;
            $('.formapago').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                var valor = $("#cliente"+id).val();
                
                 total += valor;
            })
            $("#cuenta"+tipo).val(total);
            
            console.log(total);
        });
```

```html
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


         <table>
    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text"  id="cliente1" value="100">
            </td>
            <td>
                    <select  data-id="1" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                        <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                        <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                        <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                    </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"  id="cliente2" value="50">
                </td>
                <td>
                        <select  data-id="2" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                            <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                            <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                            <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                        </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"  id="cliente3" value="100">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <select  data-id="3" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                                <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                                <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                                <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"  id="cliente4" value="30">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <select  data-id="4" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                                <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                                <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                                <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
    
    </table>
    
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Total cuenta uno
                        <input type="text" id="cuenta1">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Total cuenta Dos
                        <input type="text" id="cuenta2">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Total Pendiente
                        <input type="text" id="cuenta3">
                        </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

los errores que tenias son los siguientes :

- la variable tipo tiene que estar dentro del foreach, porque cada elemente `.formapago` tiene un tipo distinto.
- faltaban 2 variables para diferenciar los totales, ya que son mas de 1
- al sumarle el valor al total, le estabas concatenando un pedazo de texto, por eso la suma no se hacia correctamente, esto simplemente se corrije con un `parseInt(valor)` para que no sea texto.
- le faltaba a su vez una condición que permitiera direccionar cada valor al total correcto.
- y en fin se le agregan a los 3 campos de total el valor de la suma

```js
$(".formapago").change(function (e) {
    var total = 0, total2 = 0, total3 = 0;
    $('.formapago').each(function(){
        var tipo = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var valor = $("#cliente"+id).val();
         if (tipo == "1")
          total += parseInt(valor);
         if (tipo == "2")
          total2 += parseInt(valor);
         if (tipo == "3")
          total3 += parseInt(valor);
    })
    $("#cuenta1").val(total);
    $("#cuenta2").val(total2);
    $("#cuenta3").val(total3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


         <table>
    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text"  id="cliente1" value="100">
            </td>
            <td>
                    <select  data-id="1" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                        <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                        <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                        <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                    </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"  id="cliente2" value="50">
                </td>
                <td>
                        <select  data-id="2" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                            <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                            <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                            <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                        </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"  id="cliente3" value="100">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <select  data-id="3" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                                <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                                <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                                <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"  id="cliente4" value="30">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <select  data-id="4" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                                <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                                <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                                <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
    
    </table>
    
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Total cuenta uno
                        <input type="text" id="cuenta1">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Total cuenta Dos
                        <input type="text" id="cuenta2">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Total Pendiente
                        <input type="text" id="cuenta3">
                        </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

espero que te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".formapago").change(function () {
    var total1 = 0;
    var total2 = 0;
    var total3 = 0;
    
    $('.formapago').each(function () {
        var tipo = $(this).val();
        
        switch (tipo) {
            case '1':
                total1 += parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('.cliente').val());
                break;
            case '2':
                total2 += parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('.cliente').val());
                break;
            case '3':
                total3 += parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('.cliente').val());
                break;
        }
    });
    
    $('#cuenta1').val(total1);
    $('#cuenta2').val(total2);
    $('#cuenta3').val(total3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


         <table>
    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text"  id="cliente1" value="100" class="cliente">
            </td>
            <td>
                    <select  data-id="1" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                        <option value="0"  >Selecciona cuenta</option>
                        <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                        <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                        <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                    </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"  id="cliente2" value="50" class="cliente">
                </td>
                <td>
                        <select  data-id="2" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                            <option value="0"  >Selecciona cuenta</option>
                            <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                            <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                            <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                        </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"  id="cliente3" value="100" class="cliente">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <select  data-id="3" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                                <option value="0"  >Selecciona cuenta</option>
                                <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                                <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                                <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"  id="cliente4" value="30" class="cliente">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <select  data-id="4" class="formapago" name="tipop">
                                <option value="0"  >Selecciona cuenta</option>
                                <option value="1"  >cuenta uno</option>
                                <option value="2"  >cuenta dos</option>
                                <option value="3"  >pendiente</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
    
    </table>
    
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Total cuenta uno
                        <input type="text" id="cuenta1">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Total cuenta Dos
                        <input type="text" id="cuenta2">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Total Pendiente
                        <input type="text" id="cuenta3">
                        </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Tenías un poco liado el script. Te explico lo que hice:

Lo primero de todo que hice fue poner un `<option>` más a cada `<select>`, de esa manera, al dispararse el cálculo con un evento `change` conseguimos que al cargar la página no haga faltar calcular nada.

Esto a nivel de **HTML**, entrando en **Javascript** lo que hice fue inicializar unas variables, que son las que guardarán los valores acumulados dependiendo del valor del `<select>` elegido. Luego, se recorre cada uno de los `<option>` y se recupera el valor del `<input>` que se encuentra dentro del mismo `<tr>` que él, sumándolo al total de la variable que le corresponda por el valor del `<select>`.

Una vez se han recorrido todos los `<select>` se insertan los totales en sus `input` correspondiente.

Comment: Es muy asertiva esta respuesta ya que no se muestran los totales hasta que se seleccione cada cuenta. En la respuesta de @federico puede pasar que el usuario olvide cambiar la cuenta uno (que aparece por defecto). Esta situación puede inducir a errores humanos.

Comment: @DjCrazy Es como he entendido la situación. Quizás haya sido aventurar demasiado, pero al ver los values de los input con un valor fijo me imaginé que se habían puesto así por cuestión de pruebas, ya que al ser input text se pueden modificar por el usaurio. Al poner los select con un option "Sin cuenta" obligas al usuario a elegir valor y a que cuenta lo quiere asociar.